# How to test in Jest the MediaQuerList.addListener

Tags: reactjs, testing, media-queries, jestjs

I would like to test that my function has been triggered properly (with the right parameters) but I can't find a way to make it...

I have a custom addEventListener take the name of the media query, the media query itself and a dispatch function

```
// ... Inside my class
addEventListener(name, mediaQuery, dispatch) {
  // Initialize the mediaQueryList and store it in our list
  const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia(mediaQuery);
  mediaQueryList.addListener(
    mediaQueryListEvent => this.onScreenChange(name, mediaQueryListEvent)
  );
  this.mediaQueries.set(name, {
    mediaQueryList,
    dispatch
  });

  // Then we look even for the first time on which breakPoint we are
  this.searchAndDispatchBreakpoint(name, mediaQueryList);
}
```

Any idea how I can test that my onScreenChange has been properly called with the right arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after hours and hours of search and tries, I figured out a way.

I succeed in mocking the window.matchMedia and the addListener inside
Once done, I just have to test the arguments sent to my method.

Here is my jest test

```
it('should test the media query addListener method', () => {
  const bpManager = new BreakpointManager();
  const mediaQuery = 'max-width: 1080px';
  const name = 'name';
  const mediaQueryListEvent = 'mediaQueryListEvent';

  bpManager.onScreenChange = jest.fn();
  window.matchMedia = jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: e => e(mediaQueryListEvent),
    removeListener: jest.fn(),
  }));

  bpManager.addEventListener(name, mediaQuery, dispatch);
  expect(window.matchMedia).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mediaQuery);
  expect(bpManager.onScreenChange).toBeCalledWith(name, mediaQueryListEvent);
});
```

And my method addEventListener

```
addEventListener(name, mediaQuery, dispatch) {
  // Initialize the mediaQueryList and store it in our list
  const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia(mediaQuery);
  mediaQueryList.addListener(
    mediaQueryListEvent => this.onScreenChange(name, mediaQueryListEvent)
  );
  this.mediaQueries.set(name, {
    mediaQueryList,
    dispatch
  });

  // Then we look even for the first time on which breakPoint we are
  this.searchAndDispatchBreakpoint(name, mediaQueryList);
}
```

Comment: I am struggling with similar issue of testing the onChange hook for media query but in regards to theme. Posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77560014/2942897