# Mock media query change event

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dom, jestjs

I am working on writing Jest unit tests in my Angular app.

I have a theme service that handles checking and setting users default theme. In particular, there is a function that listens to changes to system preferred theme:

```
  private listenForPreferredThemeChange(): void {
    window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')
      .addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        this.setSystemTheme(e.matches ? 'dark' : 'light');
        this.appRef.tick();
      });
  }
```

I have the entire service covered with tests, but I am missing a test scenario to handle when a user changes their preferred theme in the browser settings or OS.

I have the window object mocked in my test like so:

```
  beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, "matchMedia", {
      writable: true,
      value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
        matches: null,
        media: query,
        addEventListener: jest.fn(),
        dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
      }))
    });
  });
```

I need a unit tests that goes something like so:

```
  it('should update system preferred theme', () => {
    ...
    // do something to dispatch change event to trigger change i matchMedia event listener in service
  });
```

Everything I have tried thus far does not work, and everything I can find online is just about how to mock the initial window object. What i need specifically is how to trigger a change event about that property specifically, after the fact.